# Upload Profile Pic. Cannot assign photo picked from library to profilepic in users node

Tags: swift, firebase

```
     func uploadProfileImage(_ image:UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_ url:URL?)->())) {

           let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profileImages").child("\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpg")


          guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) else { return }

           let metaData = StorageMetadata()
           metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

       storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata:metaData) { (metaData, error) in
           if error != nil, metaData != nil {
               storageRef.downloadURL (completion: {(url, error) in
                   if error != nil {
                   if let downloadurl = url?.absoluteString {
                   if (self.profilePicLink == "") {
                   self.profilePicLink = downloadurl
                      Database.database().reference().child("users").child(self.uid).updateChildValues(["profilePicLink":downloadurl])
                   }
               }

           }   else {
               completion(nil)
               }
           }
               )
       }

           }

     }
```

I am trying to assign upload photo from my library and then assign it to profilePicLink. When I choose pic from my library, it appears in the UIImage ImageView frame, however. When I use these func and action to update avatar it went error

```
 @IBAction func updateAvatar(_ sender: Any) {
        uploadPhoto()
    }

    func uploadPhoto(){
        selectedUser?.uploadProfileImage(imageView.image!){
            url in print (URL.self)
        }

    }
```

After I check in Firestore, there is no pic stored and my profilePicLink has no value.
Please be advised on this

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `error != nil, metadata != nil` together. It's contradicting each other hence that condition is never executed. Change it to:

```
if error == nil, metadata != nil {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I changed as you advised however it went error when I called uploadProfileImage for selectedUser as  Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
  func uploadPhoto(){
        selectedUser?.uploadProfileImage(imageView.image!){
            url in print (URL.self)
        }
     
    }